# Why is this IF statement still firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, resize, window-resize

Ok, so a long time user of Stackoverflow, first time question-er. Bare in mind I'm mainly a CSS/HTML guy and only know jQuery basics so be gentle!

Why oh why is this `if` statement still firing, even when the target element is not available in the HTML? See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/n8nAq/) (view console log), it happens when there is no `.cta > .btn` on the page also. The section to look for is:

```
if ( $('.page-template') ) {

}
```

Here's the [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/dTKSY/) for reference. This probably won't be too slow loading anyway but I'd like to limit what is working in the background, especially `window resize` as I've heard it's a resource hog (using Paul Irish script).

If it's anything like PHP it shouldn't fire at all right?

**UPDATE**

So I've since stumbled upon [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) which does the same job as an `if` statement but only returns an object if the class exists. So the following as an example:

```
$(function() {
  $('.nav-main .active.dropdown').is(
    function(){
  $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('visuallyhidden')
  .parents('#menu-primary-navigation').addClass('dropdown-active');
  console.log('is fired');
}
  );
});
```

Only fires if `.nav-main .active.dropdown` is available. So I imagine (untested) the following would also work:

```
if ( $('something').is() ) { ... }
```

**UPDATE #02**

You can also specify "is not" by using the exlamation mark `!`, like this:

```
if ( !$('something') ) { ... }
```

Comment: That's because it's true. In your HTML you have the following code `<div class="page-template">`. The period in jQuery is the same as in CSS and stands for a class. The working example has `<div class="no-page-template">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( $('.page-template').length ) {

}
```

I believe just doing `$('.page-template')` will still return an object, which evaluates to true. If you want to check if the element exists you'll have to use `length`.

Comment: Some kind of dirty trick that the length of 0 is false, but quiet good +1.

Comment: Ok so I kind of get it, the modernizr.mq is querying the length of the browser window, so you check that it is, and if not it shouldn't fire? That does seems to be working yes, after saving that out as a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8nAq/1/ ... nice work gentleman, why haven't I used StackOverflow sooner?!

Comment: A friend on Twitter explained it further: _jQuery 'request' will be empty if the element doesn't exist, basically the 'length' property will be 0_ [here](https://twitter.com/scrwd/status/325707793724223488) and [here](https://twitter.com/scrwd/status/325710281063952384)

Answer (score 2):

`$('.page-template')` returns a jQuery object and objects are truthy in Javascript, so that `if` statement is always entered.

If you want to check how many elements the selector matched you can access the `length` property of the jQuery object which will be `0` if the selector didn't match anything and since `0` is falsy it will behave the way you expect:

```
if ( $('.page-template').length )
```

Comment: Yes, that gives me a much better idea of how it works. So I expect I could use this for any `if` statement as a quick way of checking if the object exists. Nice! I'd +1 if I could ;)